# Subscriber is to subscription as provider is to ...?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

As the title suggests I am looking for a noun which describes the connection between a person (the provider) and the objects or services he provides.

It will be used in the same context as the pair “subscriber”/“subscription”.

“Provision” sounds right, yet has a different meaning (the one of reserving).

Comment: If a word has one meaning, that is not to say it cannot have another. There is no real alternative to 'provision' if you want to be symmetrical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Provision is correct.  A provision is something provided (see definition 1 [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=9cP&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=provision&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=cBnnTo2_FY7MtgeUtrXcCg&ved=0CDUQkQ4&biw=960&bih=518)).

Answer (score 6):

*Provision* is a word with multiple meanings; it can refer to a legal stipulation, an advance measure, food (typically in the plural), and *that which is provided*.

Thus, the word *provision* is actually accurate in this context.

That said, it's true that the word's other meanings have the potential to confuse careless readers. In that case, an unambiguous word like *product* might be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of *subscriber/subscription*, for example a newspaper subscriber, then the provider provides the subscription to the subscriber.

So the provider might say:

> As the provider, we will provide your subscription for a monthly fee.